# Android Studio Estimote Beacon Application

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon

im trying to make basic beacon application in android studio. I just want to scan beacons and list them into the screen. Here are my codes. I took them from somewhere.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private static final String ESTIMOTE_PROXIMITY_UUID = "B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D";
private static final Region ALL_ESTIMOTE_BEACONS = new Region("regionId", null, null, null);

private BeaconManager beaconManager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    beaconManager.setRangingListener(new BeaconManager.RangingListener() {
        @Override public void onBeaconsDiscovered(Region region, List<Beacon> beacons) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Ranged beacons: " + beacons);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    beaconManager.connect(new BeaconManager.ServiceReadyCallback() {
        @Override public void onServiceReady() {
            try {
                beaconManager.startRanging(ALL_ESTIMOTE_BEACONS);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                Log.e("TAG","Cannot start ranging", e);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    try {
        beaconManager.stopRanging(ALL_ESTIMOTE_BEACONS);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        Log.e("TAG", "Cannot stop but it does not matter now", e);
    }
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    beaconManager.disconnect();
}
}
```

Here is my manifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.oem.estimote_ibeacon_app" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service 
        android:name="com.estimote.sdk.service.BeaconService"
        android:exported="false"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

When i opened application it says "stopped" please help. I have beacons for test. Where is my mistake? Thank you.

Comment: Please add Logcat/stacktrace. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Sorry, here is the logcat: http://paste2.org/_WcU0FwhD

Answer (score 0):

it seems that ALL_ESTIMOTE_BEACONS in

```
beaconManager.startRanging(ALL_ESTIMOTE_BEACONS);
```

is null.

enter a valid regionid instead of "regionid" in

```
private static final Region ALL_ESTIMOTE_BEACONS = new Region("regionId", null, null, null);
```